# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException inserting JTable data to SQL database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jtable

I have made a project on railway management system and want to insert values from text fields and Java table to MySQL database. How can I get rid of this error? Please help!!

```
int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
for(int row = 0; row<rows ; row++){
    int index=1;
    String S_No = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
    String Name = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
    String Age = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3);
    String Gender = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 4);
    String berth_preference = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 5);
    String Quota = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 6);
    String tno =(String) cb1.getSelectedItem();
    String tname =(String) cb2.getSelectedItem();
    String clas =(String) cb3.getSelectedItem();
    String tic= tick.getText();
    String frms=frm.getText();
    String tos=to.getText();
    String boarding=bp.getText();
    String reser=ru.getText();
    String jdate=date.getText();
    String pnr=l1.getText();

    try{
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/railway","root","ridhi");
        st =con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pnr(pnr_no,Train_Number,Train_Name,From_m,T_o,Date,Class,Reserved_Upto,Boarding_Pt,no_tickets,S_No,Name,Age,Gender,berth_preference,Quota) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        st.setString(1, S_No);
        st.setString(2, Name);
        st.setString(3, Age);
        st.setString(4, Gender);
        st.setString(5, berth_preference);
        st.setString(6, Quota);

        st.executeUpdate();
        index++;

        this.setVisible(true);
        new payment().setVisible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 >= 6
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:277)
at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(JTable.java:2553)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2695)
at reservation.reservationActionPerformed(reservation.java:341)
at reservation.access$100(reservation.java:21)
at reservation$2.actionPerformed(reservation.java:245)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6216)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5981)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4583)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4220)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4150)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

---

And now I am getting a new error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ).
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3272)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4108)
at reservation.reservationActionPerformed(reservation.java:358)
at reservation.access$100(reservation.java:21)
at reservation$2.actionPerformed(reservation.java:245)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6216)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5981)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4583)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4220)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4150)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this to this jtable columns are zero index based.if you have 6 columns of jtable then max column index is 5 not 6 .error is because of this but care about row index 2 if you want to get first row then `getValueAt(0, n);` not `getValueAt(1, n);`

```
String S_No = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0);
String Name = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
String Age = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
String Gender = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3);
String berth_preference = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 4);
String Quota = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 5);// 5 not 6
```

you should have same column count in prepared statement also .

```
 st =con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pnr(pnr_no,Train_Number,Train_Name,From_m,T_o,Date,Class,Reserved_Upto,Boarding_Pt,no_tickets,S_No,Name,Age,Gender,berth_preference,Quota) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

...........................................................................................

```
 st.setString(1, S_No);
 st.setString(2, Name);
 st.setString(3, Age);
 st.setString(4, Gender);
 st.setString(5, berth_preference);
 st.setString(6, Quota);
```

you should have like, you have missed column phone number train number

```
 st.setString(1, pnr);
 st.setString(2, tno );
```

Comment: @ridhi yes sorry 6 columns mean column 0,1,2,3,4,5 not 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: @ridhi in which line ? how much rows exist in your jtable?can you show your jtable ?

Comment: S_no | name | age | gender |   Berth_preference |  quota

Comment: its not showing the line... when I click submit button the  error is shown   in  message dialog box.

Comment: @ridhi after you change 6 to 5,can you post the new  error msg .also you can change `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());` to `e.printStackTrace();` to avoid popup

Comment: S_no | name | age | gender |   Berth_preference |  quota
these are the columns of my jtable. n it has 6 rows but there's no restriction that all the rows should be filled .depends on the user how many tickets he wants to book.

Comment: I did change 6to 5 .after that only this error : parameter index out of range 0<1. pops up

Comment: @ridhi the new error is not came from jtable it came from sql .check columns of your mysql table

Comment: |pnr_no |(NO >PRI >NULL  >auto_increment )

|Train_Number  
Train_Name      
| Fro_m                    
| T_o                             
| Date             
| Class            
| Reserved_Upto    
| Boarding_Pt      
| no_tickets       
| S_No             
| Name             
| Age              
| Gender          
| berth_preference 
| Quota

Comment: @ridhi if your mysql table have 10 columns then your prepared also should 10 prepared statement should have .in your code there is only 6 `st.setString()` you should add all columns like that where is setString or int for phone number ?train number

Comment: u mean I should add prepared statement also for the columns I am inserting values through combo box and text feild

Comment: @ridhi yes of couse .but corresponding value to `st =con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pnr(pnr_no,Train_Number,Train_Name,From_m,T_o,Date,Class,Reserved_Upto,Boarding_Pt,no_tickets,S_No,Name,Age,Gender,berth_preference,Quota) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");`

st.setString(1,x) , x should be value of  pnr_no which is pnr 
st.setString(2,x) , x should be value of  pTrain_Number which is tno

Comment: I wish I could post the screenshot here. it would have been lot more easier .

Comment: ohh I thought these int values areonly for values from jtable... one more thing here st.setString(0,x); or st.setString(1,x).

Comment: @ridhi  it's `st.setString(1,x)` because it's not jtable it's for prepared statement it's start with index 1

Answer (score 0):

When *`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`* is shown: If we request for an index that is either negative, or greater than or equal to the size of the array, an *`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`* is thrown.
In your case, `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 >= 6`.